# How can I keep track of changes to my website over time?

Tags: change-management

Sometimes the boss wants to know who changed something on the website or changes their mind several times on where a button should go, what color something is, or whether or not a page should show up at all.  Is there a simple way for a small 2-3 person web team to keep track of these constant changes?

Answer (score 7):

Use source control.  Specifically, I would check out http://git-scm.com/ and http://mercurial.selenic.com/.  They are both great Source Control platforms and are cheap (free if you host it yourself).

Also, Git and Mercurial allow you to have 1 solution for all your developers and handles branching and merging very easily.  It will also show who changed what, when they changed it, etc.

Comment: To use Mercurial as revision control for web development see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/262/how-would-i-setup-mercurial-to-track-site-revisions-on-a-shared-host.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is basically what you hinted at in the tags: Use a source control system.
If you are using a CMS for the website that may be able to track the changes for you (i.e. have a source control system built in).

Otherwise you can simply install a system yourself.

Given the size of your team I would go for Mercurial because it has all the modern features and is very easy to setup and use. If you guys work under Windows I'ld simply install [TortoiseHG](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) and read [this tutorial](http://hginit.com/) by Joel Spolsky.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying a hosted version control solution like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) just to get the feel of it. It is very easy to set up and free to try out.

(I don't work for Beanstalk. There are other similar services).