# How would I setup Mercurial to track site revisions on a shared host?

Tags: shared-hosting

What specific steps to I need to take to set it up?

Do I need special post-commit hooks to update the remote copy of the site?

Do I need SSH access to the remote server?

I'm looking for a setup where I can push the changes to the remote repository and the changes will be published to the website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure Mercurial to run a web server using the [`hg serve` command](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Serve). A list of runtime options on hg serve are available [here](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#serve).

Once you have your web server set up, `hg clone http://servername:port` will pull a copy of the server's resources, and `hg push` from that directory will update the server.

To force the server to update itself upon receiving a new push, add [the following](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-CommonProblems.Any_way_to_.27hg_push.27_and_have_an_automatic_.27hg_update.27_on_the_remote_server.3F) to the .hg/hgrc file in the repository:

```
[hooks]
changegroup = hg update >&2
```

This should accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: Wow... thank you so much. I think I searched google for 4 hours and still couldn't find a good answer to this question.

Comment: My pleasure! :)  It took me a lot of searching to figure this out, too.

Comment: one other question. Would I still need to install mercurial on the remote server over SSH?

Comment: SSH or at the console directly, yes.

Comment: I'm going to modify one of my tutorials to include your last suggestion, with proper attribution of course :)